# Type Narrowing an element in an array with `find`

Tags: typescript

If I have an array filled with items of a union type and I want to find an element within the array and work with it, knowing from my `find` that I have narrowed the type, how do I accomplish this?

That is, if I have the following types:

```
interface A {
  text: string;
}
interface B {
  type: string;
}
type C = A|B;
```

and the following code

```js
const arr: Array<C> = [....]
```

I want to find the first element of `arr` that has a `type` attribute.

Logically, I think this is represented by

```js
const output = arr.find(child => {
  if ('type' in child) return true;
  return false
})
```

This seems like it should narrow the type of `output` to be `B`, but it doesn't. The compiler still seems to think that `output` is of type `C`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use a typeguard:

```
function isB(c: C) c is B {
   return typeof (c as B).type === 'string';
}


const output = arr.find(isB);
```

the typeguard tells TypeScript what's going on so it can infer the type.

edited to check the type of type is string, since apparently that's possible

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210297/discussion-on-answer-by-bryan60-type-narrowing-an-element-in-an-array-with-find).

Answer (score 3):

The type safe way to implement the type guard in your case is

```
function isB(c: C): c is B {
    if ('type' in c) { 
        return typeof c.type === 'string';
    }

    return false;
}
```

The other answer does not take into account the fact that there are valid `C` values that have `type` property that is not a string.

Comment: There are? How can a `C` have a `type` that isn't a string?

Comment: @ABMagil easily https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgILIN4FgBQzmQAeYAXMgM5hSgDmA3LgL66iSyIoBCmu+YAngAcIZStRD0muAcOQBhZAF40yAD7JODHLgQB7EJWQA3JZgIRiZAOQxduqwBoCQkcgAsAJieMtO-YYQyBWUjOiA

Comment: Another way to say it is that TypeScript doesn't do type narrowing based on property names. As @zerkms showed, something of type `A` could have a property `type`. Something being of type `A` does not mean it does not have any extra properties. Typescript only prevents literal objects from having extra properties, that's why the example does a separate assignment.

Comment: Oops what I said is actually wrong, TypeScript does know on the line that says `return false` that c is of type `B`. It just doesn't propagate that knowledge to the return of `find()` See https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#using-the-in-operator That means adding the typeguard will not help, I wanted to take my upvote back but it won't let me.  See https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-1gvqw  Lastly, the type of c in your typeguard should be `(c: B | C)` so it could be used in the `find`. Please update your answer, I want to delete my comment above

Comment: @JuanMendes your original comment is actually correct, and the second one is not.

Comment: @zerkms Let's discuss this in chat https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210297/discussion-on-answer-by-bryan60-type-narrowing-an-element-in-an-array-with-find

Answer (score 1):

In further searching, I stumbled across https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20218

From there, I found the comment

> a => isCat(a) isn't explicitly annotated as being a type predicate, and we don't infer those.

As the others state, the solution is to use an explicit type guard as the predicate function. replacing the arrow function with some user-defined type guard `isC` fixes the problem.

Comment: The type guard does not change the type of `output` in your example. Not sure what you mean by "fixes the problem" . See https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-playground-export-1gvqw

Answer (score 1):

Since the other answers here seem to focus more on how to make absolutely sure that an object does in fact satisfy the interface `B`, I will try to answer the question of how to propagate the narrowing in the callback to the return value of `find`:

Actually @zerkms and @bryan60 seem to be correct in that a type guard is needed, but all you need to add to your code is the type predicate `child is B` like this:

```js
const output = arr.find((child): child is B => {
  if ('type' in child) return true;
  return false
})
```

Beware, however, that this is you telling the compiler what type the child must be whenever the callback returns a truthy value. So the narrowing that the compiler does for you inside the callback is NOT actually propagated, and if you later change the interfaces, or the type C, or the logic inside the callback, this predicate will keep assuring the compiler that `output` is either `B` or `undefined`, which may or may not be true.